# Find keywords from a webpage/website

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

I have the code that can find the word from a specific url/webpage

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/furniture');
if (preg_match("/Sofa /i", "$homepage")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

What i want to know is that is it possible to fetch the keyword "sofa" and its related detail such as type and cost from the entire website www.example.com dynamically

Comment: Please post an example of "type and cost", also, it's difficult to help without a real live example.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possbile to fetch data from website but Most website do not allow direct  access because of spamming and security issue .

- You can use Php library [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/)
- Or Inject Javascript links in webpages .